# I gave my full name and phone number and details to deposit money on my debit card for me to make a purchase for them

Tags: scams, uae

I gave my debit card number ny full name and phone number and my email address and password to someone so they could deposit funds to my card to make a purchase with and then mail that purchase to them minus one for myself I have closed the account for my card so they can't do anything with that but he still has all the rest of my information what can I do

Comment: change your password. If you use that password in more than one place change it in those other places too. The deposit will likely bounce (if it was ever made at all).

Comment: I'm curious what it was that changed your mind about going along with this "someone"'s scheme to realizing it was a scam?

Comment: Why on Earth did you do this? Why not buy It yourself?

Comment: Stop giving out passwords to your most sensitive information!!

Answer (score 10):

Contact your bank ***immediately***, if you haven't done so already.  They will almost certainly have some sort of "fraud hotline" which can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 3):

Close your card, now. Let your credit card provider / bank know about the situation.

Never, ever ever, give out your password. Not to a friend, not to your bank and not even to your cat.

Comment: Yes, my cat is a bastard! :D

Comment: I joined this forum just to upvote your comment @PeterK.

Answer (score 3):

Also, do not trust anyone who phones you up. If someone phones up, claiming to be your bank, and trying to "sort out this situation"; how do you know it's your bank? You've given the scammer your phone number - it could be the scammer calling.

Only discuss this with someone at the bank when *you* have phoned *them*.